# angular2 toggle icon on ngFor

Tags: angular

My angular2 problem is that the icon is not visible when i arrive to the page but only after click. my array is "keys"

```
<ion-grid class="dueD-line" *ngFor="let line of keys; let i=index">
<div style="margin-bottom: 6%;" (click)="toggleDetails(line)">
<ion-col class="first-title-row first-title-row-size" text-left align-items: left col-9>Line {{i+1}}</ion-col>
<ion-col class="first-title-row first-title-row-size" text-right align-items: right col-3><ion-icon class="arrow-right"  item-right name="ios-arrow-down-outline"></ion-icon><ion-icon class="arrow-right"  item-right name={{line.icon}}></ion-icon></ion-col>
</div>
<div *ngIf="line.showDetails">
{{line.text}}
</ion-grid>

export class ReviewCartPage implements OnInit {

  keys: any;
  icon: string;

constructor(){
this.icon = 'ios-arrow-down-outline';
}

toggleDetails(line) {
    if (line.showDetails) {
      line.showDetails = false;
      line.icon = 'ios-arrow-down-outline';
    } else {
      line.showDetails = true;
      line.icon = 'ios-arrow-up-outline';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component class:

```
showDetails = 1;
keys = [{ id: 1, icon: 'ios-arrow-down-outline', text: "Your text for icon1" }, { id: 2, icon: 'ios-arrow-up-outline', text: "Your text for icon2" }]

toggleDetails(id) {
    this.showDetails = id;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div style="color:red; display:flex;" *ngFor="let line of keys">
    <span *ngIf="showDetails==line.id">{{line.icon}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="showDetails==line.id">{{line.text}}</span>
    <button (click)="toggleDetails(line.id)">click</button>
</div>
```

This way your "lines" will show only if the button is clicked. The first one would be by default. You have to populate the 'keys' array first.
The error you were commiting was this.icon = 'ios-arrow-down-outline';